# Strange behaviour with asp.net and javascript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This follows on from my question earlier about Visual Studio showing `""` instead of `"`.

When I run the code below it creates a javascript array and returned as `res[0]` like below:

```
["Name","Name","Name"]
```

in visual studio it returns this:

```
"["Name","Name","Name"]"
```

When I run the code, this part shows the surrounding speech marks still (autocompletedata):

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("rd-search-form-input"), autocompletedata );
```

This causes the code to not work. When i manually remove the surrounding double quotes, all works fine.

I've tried removing the start and end part of the string but it just removes the `[` and `]`, which indicates that the string isn't surrounded by double quotes at all. I've also tried removing all double quotes but to no avail.

Can anyone explain whats going wrong?

```
var urlMethod = "/ajax.aspx/GetTeamMemberNamesList";
var params = new Object();
var result;

params.TeamID = 123;

result = SendAjaxSingleValue(urlMethod, params);
var res = result.d.split("|");

var autocompletedata = res[0];

autocompletedata.replace(/['"]+/g, '')

autocomplete(document.getElementById("rd-search-form-input"), autocompletedata );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the solution from the OP, the ajax call returns not the array itself but a JSON string, as is always the case when receiving data from a web server - hence why `res[0]` is returned as `["Name","Name","Name"]`.

Hence, in order to turn the response text into an actual array, it requires `JSON.parse` to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was annoying - this fixed my issue:

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("rd-search-form-input"), JSON.parse(autocompletedata));
```